# fluent nhibernate not generating schema correctly on function

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a funny feeling this is just my understanding of nHibernate and Fluent nHibernate.

I have a small console application which exports a schema based on a bunch of entity classes. Everything works great until I do this:

```
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual string UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<UserAttribute> UserAttributes { get; set; }

    /** CODE IN QUESTION **/
    public virtual string GetAttributeValue(string name)
    {
        var value = UserAttributes.FirstOrDefault(ua => ua.AttributeDefinition.AttributeName == name);
        if (value != null)
            return value.Value;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
```

If I comment out the function, everything works great.  Even if I just have the function return string.Empty, everything works.  However, once I add back the line:

```
var value = UserAttributes.FirstOrDefault(ua => ua.AttributeDefinition.AttributeName == name);
```

Everything breaks with this error:

```
"The entity '<>c__DisplayClass1' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id)."
```

I am using auto mapping.  What is the cause of this error?  I understand the error normally, but it looks like it's failing on an anonymous class.  Do I just have a bad misunderstanding about how this is all supposed to work together?  I am definitely a nHibernate newbie, both in practice and in philosophy.  I'd love to be enlightened!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the lambda `ua => ua.AttributeDefinition.AttributeName == name` generates an inner class to capture the name parameter. The automapper walks over every type and tries to map it and unfortunatly also picks up the compiler generated one.

You could implement an AutomappingConfiguration to exclude the compiler generated classes

```
class MyAutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return !type.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false) && base.ShouldMap(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firo - my knee jerk reaction is that this behavior is a bug in Automapping - would you agree?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing myself... this looks good, I'll test it out in the next hour or so.

Comment: @TomBushell i would say so. please file an issue if it is so.

Comment: Awesome @Firo this solved it for me. I'm on FNH 1.3.0.733 and NH v3.3.1.4000 and the bug still exists in these versions. I did not see it on the issues list on github so not sure that they know about it.

Comment: correction - heres the github post [Automap tries to map anonymous classes](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/146)

Answer (score 0):

Though, @Firo answer above works, it does not seem to work when you have Linq queries within another Linq query. Example:

```
DataTable Dt = FillData();
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> MasterProfileRows = null;
IList<RecordOwner> OwnedRecs = new List<RecordOwner>();
OwnedRecs.Add(new RecordOwner { ForeignRecordKey = 100 });
MasterProfileRows = from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where OwnedRecs.Any(y => y.ForeignRecordKey.ToString() == x.Field<object>("ProfileID").ToString())
                    select x;
```

To work around this, I added this into my override to check the number of occurrences of "__displayclass" in the FullName of the class and if its greater than 1, we ignore mapping it.

```
public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
{
    // there is a bug where the fluent automapper tries to automap anonymous types within a lambda. the !type.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false) works around this issue
    // except where there is a nest linq query.
    // see: 
    // https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/issues/146
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446155/fluent-nhibernate-not-generating-schema-correctly-on-function/11447966#11447966
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268568/odd-error-building-fluentnh-configuration
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446155/fluent-nhibernate-not-generating-schema-correctly-on-function/11447966
    // ignore nested linq queries (linq queries within linq queries) because they cause the auto mapper to error out.
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("__displayclass", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if(reg.Matches(type.FullName).Count > 1)
        return false;

    return !type.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false);
}
```