# Odd error building FluentNH configuration

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a Fluent NHibernate project I'm working on, and doing some testing I have run into a very strange error:

`The entity '<>c__DisplayClass3' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id).`

The related entity reported is:

`{Name = "<>c__DisplayClass3" FullName = "TPLLCPortal.Domain.Account+<>c__DisplayClass3"}`

I don't have any class named `DisplayClass`, but I do have an `Account` entity. I'm using a primary key convention that looks like this:

```
public class PrimaryKeyConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
    }
}
```

My `Account` class inherits from an `EntityBase` class that declares the ID as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the id.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The id.</value>
public virtual Guid Id { get; protected internal set; }
```

I'm confident that I'm setting up the configuration properly and that the conventions are being picked up, but just in case I added an override and specifically mapped the ID for the `Account` class. No dice.

Any ideas what's going on here?

I'm using FNH 1.3.0.733 with NHibernate 3.3.1.4000 (both loaded off NuGet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11447966/240439) had the key. Because some of the methods on the class use lambdas, the compiler creates classes that you can exclude in the `DefaultAutomappingConfiguration` by specifying `!type.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)` as part of the `ShouldMap` override.